# How to use a Fragment to run an AsyncTask that uses ProgressDialog and can survive an Orientation Change

Tags: android

I was following the example in CommonsWare's book on how to use a Fragment to handle orientation changes for an async task (using setRetainInstance(true)). I then tried to add a progress dialog to the async task but it keeps crashing on orientation change saying "view not attached to window."

Is there a pattern for using a progress dialog inside of an asynctask that is inside of a fragment that will not lose the progress dialog or crash when the orientation changes?

Do I still have to manage the life cycle of the progress dialog w/in the fragment, even though the fragment is not being destroyed? I'm assuming that since the progress dialog gets created on the activity's UI that maybe I have to destroy/recreate the progress dialog by overriding the onAttach() and onDetach() methods of the fragment? However, I thought that Android was supposed to take care of reattaching the activity if I use fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the design guidelines the ProgressDialog seems obsolete. Looks like we're just supposed to use a spinner or bar and no text. Given this info, I think the correct route is to use a spinner as the fragment's layout and embed that layout w/in the main activity's layout. That way showing/hiding it can be managed from the fragment, thereby handling the orientation change.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the following error.

```
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.ui.SmsVerificationActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at com.my.app.ui.SmsVerificationActivity.initResources(SmsVerificationActivity.java:52)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at com.my.app.ui.SmsVerificationActivity.onCreate(SmsVerificationActivity.java:29)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-27 17:38:07.647: E/AndroidRuntime(7863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Here's my layout for the main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:text="@string/sms_verification_header"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verification_description_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="@string/sms_verification_step_one"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dip" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/verification_description_text"
            android:background="#808080" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="phone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/async_verification_fragment"
        android:name="com.my.app.ui.AsyncVerificationFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/connect_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/verify"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/yes" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragment layout:

And the offending line of code in the main activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.sms_verification_activity);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        initResources();


    }

    private void initResources() {

        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final String number = tm.getLine1Number();

        mPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(number)) {
            mPhoneNumber.setText(number);
        }

        final Button verify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verify);
```

Here's the onCreateView for the fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress_bar, container);

        return v;
    }
```